# Do some of the icicles contain loot?

Tags: bioshock

**Do some of the icicles hanging from the ceiling, like the one in the [screenshot below,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ER0Z.jpg) contain any loot? Is there a particular area where icicles are likely to contain loot?**

I'm asking because there are quite a lot of them in the area where I'm currently at. And I'm wondering if I'm wasting EVE trying to melt every icicle I see with Incinerate, when they might not contain loot anyway.

[image]

Note: I already know that some of the ice contain loot. I'm just not sure about the icicles I mentioned, since I've already wasted tons of EVE on melting all icicles I encounter, and have yet to see loot come from one of them.

Comment: IN-CI-NERATE ! IN-CI-NERATE !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icicles hanging from the ceiling almost never have loot in them. Don't bother melting them unless you've got plenty of EVE to spare (i.e. there are tons of EVE hypos laying around nearby you can't pick up because you're full).

Comment: I'm talking about icicles that are hanging from the ceiling only (editing my question to reflect this). "*Usually when an icicle has loot you'll be able to actually see the loot inside it.*" Does this apply on icicles hanging from the ceiling? Do some icicles hanging from the ceiling have loot inside them?

Comment: The dark splotches in the icicles aren't items. It is a waste to try to melt them, even if they appear to contain something.

Answer (score 1):

Rarely but yes. Just give some INCINERATE or bullet fires at it and wait for the surprise...

...although there are more loots in the ice on the floor than in the icicles.

Comment: Are you sure? I've wasted tons of EVE to cast Incinerate on all icicles I encounter, and have yet to see loot come from one of them. Is there a particular area where icicles are likely to contain loot? In what area have you seen an icicle contain loot?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, icicles have never contained loot. Even if they rarely did, overall it would be a huge waste of EVE. Far better loot can be found on corpses.